# Nodejs Elastic benastalk refused to connect to upsteam/ upsteam prematurely closed

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, connection-refused

I am getting the following errors when running my application in elastic beanstalk: `[error] 3636#0: *295 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream` and  `[error] 3636#0: *295 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` Its strange because if I hit those routes independently it works fine. It only appears to error when firing those routes from my vuex action.

The following is the log from the AWS elastic beanstalk.
[image]

The following is the network tab when it hits my FFmpeg route:

[image]

The following is the generate video action as fired from vuex.

```
  async [GENERATE_VIDEO]({state, rootState, dispatch, commit}){
          const username = rootState.user.currentUser.username;
          const s3Id = rootState.templates.currentVideo.stock_s3_id;
          const type = rootState.dataClay.fileFormat || state.type;
          const vid = new Whammy.fromImageArray(state.captures, 30);
             vid.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
             vid.name = "canvasVideo.webm";
          const data = new FormData();
          const id = `${username}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
          data.append("id", id);
          data.append("upload", vid);
          const projectId = await dispatch(INSERT_PROJECT);
          await dispatch(UPLOAD_TEMP_FILE, data);
      const key = await dispatch(CONVERT_FILE_TYPE, { id, username, type, projectId});
      const role = rootState.user.currentUser.role;
      state.file = `/api/files/${key}`;
      let message;
      if(role!='banner'){
        message =`<p>Your video is ready.</p> <a href="${state.file}" download class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Download</a>`;
      } else {
        message = `<p>Your video is ready. You may download your file from your banner account</p>`;
        const resolution = rootState.dataClay.matrix[0];
        await dispatch(EXPORT_TO_BANNER, { s3Id, fileUrl: key, extension: `.${type}`, resolution});
      }
```

And here are the api routes called in the actions.

```
 async [UPLOAD_TEMP_FILE]({ commit }, data) {
    try {
     const response = await axios.post("/api/canvas-editor/upload-temp", data);
     return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
async [CONVERT_FILE_TYPE]({commit}, data) {
    try{
    const response = await axios.post("/api/canvas-editor/ffmpeg", data);
    return response.data;
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
  }
  }
```

As I said all my routes work and the application runs as expected on localhost however when uploaded to aws I receive unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found out that I did not set the ffmpeg path.
Once this was done it worked great.

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

module.exports = ffmpeg;
```